# Getting an error in the test version, which is not with the normal sencha app watch command

Tags: testing, extjs, sencha-cmd

When I run "sencha app build testing" command In Ext js Application. It shows me an error "DOM element with id ext-viewport in Element cache is not the same as element in the DOM. Make sure to clean up Element instances using `destroy()"`. Here I'm running the index.html, file which is in `Build->testing->ExtUI folder`. When I run without the testing one it works perfectly. Can someone help? Ext version is 6.6

Comment: So the build step passes without any errors you just encounter the mentioned error when you try to open the app in the browser?

Comment: @scebotari66 , Yes .sench app buld command works without any error. It shows when it's opened in the browser and apears in console.

Comment: Can you update the question with the error stack trace so we would have some hints?